# How to have volume material cast shadows?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have a box with a volume material applied, affecting its density.  However, when I render the scene, the shadow of the box is still in the scene. Here is the image:

[image]

I am wondering how to either disable the shadows for that box specifically (in case there are other objects in the scene) or to make the light cast volume shadows based on the density inside the box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable *Receive transparent* in the material settings of the floor plane:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]